# what does System.Globalization.CultureInfo enGB do

Tags: asp.net, system, globalization, cultureinfo

I am new in `asp.net` and I want to know what does `System.Globalization.CultureInfo enGB` do 
Whole code(`System.Globalization.CultureInfo enGB = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) definition:

> CultureInfo provides information about a specific culture (called a
>   locale for unmanaged code development). The information includes the
>   names for the culture, the writing system, the calendar used, the sort
>   order of strings, and formatting for dates and numbers.

`CultureInfo` is used when you create an application which will potentially be accessed by users from different countries. So basically if you set the culture to English - Great Britain all the monetary amounts,dates and sort ordering will be done according to the en-GB culture.

**Example:**

```
decimal amount = 12.99M;

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");

//The amount will be displayed in pounds - £12.99
string amountPounds = amount.ToString("C");

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");

//The anount will be displayed in dollars - $12.99
string amountDollars = amount.ToString("C");
```